# Responsive 4 column grid turns to 3 column grid on resize

Tags: css, responsive-design

Ok so grid's are apparently great. I've spent the past two days looking at [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html), Twitter's [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem), [Semantic](http://semantic.gs/) and [Responsive.gs](http://responsive.gs/) and I still can't figure out a simple problem :

```
I have 4 horizontal sections with an image header and text. 
I want each to take up 25%.
```

When the screen is resized:

```
I need the rightmost section to disappear
Each remaining section should therefore take up 33%
```

If I put `.span3` classes for a 12 column grid then I'd have to use javascript to change them to `.span4` which isn't what I want.

I've looked at symentic markup (not putting magic classes in the code) but that just gets [very complicated](http://blog.appliedis.com/2013/02/04/bootstrap-with-less/) and isn't fully supported by most frameworks except Semantic.

This seems like such a simple thing but I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: for this i think you make your own `code` and on `media queries` arrange according to however you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without any fancy frameworks, here is a very straight forward example in pure CSS which takes 4 columns and makes them 3 on resize.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">First</div>
    <div class="box">Second</div>
    <div class="box">Third</div>
    <div class="box">Fourth</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box
{
    width:22%;
    margin:0px 1.5%;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    float:left;
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px)
{
    .box
    {
        width:30%;
    }
    .box:last-child
    {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XXhve/)

One important aspect is that I did not make these strictly 25% width as I wanted a margin between each. In different scenarios and markups, you could make the width 25% and just have another element inside it with the padding to make a space between each column.

I personally find it more difficult using frameworks to do responsive design (unless the entire page already heavily uses said framework) and most sites I have worked on don't take that much time to make a few custom rules and declarations.

I will note though, media queries are available on most modern browsers however I haven't seen it work in less than IE8 without JavaScript help. One such library for incompatible browsers is [css-mediaqueries-js](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/).

Comment: am also said this things +1 for Without any fancy frameworks, here is a very straight forward example. :-)

Comment: I'm definitely remembering why I dislike frameworks the last 2 days. but need to see what's out there. I'm ok with the Old-IE JS fixes

Comment: @Simon_Weaver use frameworks when you need to, but know why you use them.

Comment: Frameworks definitely have their uses otherwise they wouldn't be popular. Depending on the scale of the site you are trying to build, the compatibility and the time you have to do it, these all impact whether it is better or easier to go one way or another.

Comment: I'm also learning that responsive frameworks generally don't actually really do anything for you